# Для изображений использовать базу или хранилище?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql, хранение-данных

Всем привет!

Начинаю планировать архитектуру веб приложения, и у меня возник вопрос по поводу хранения изображений. В приложении пользователи будут загружать большое количество изображений, изначально я думал чтобы преобразовывать их в формат `webp`(так как этот формат наиболее поддается сильному сжатию) и затем сжимать. Теперь я больше склоняюсь к тому чтобы хранить эти изображения в бд, чтобы не занимать дисковое пространство. Подскажите как лучше хранить большое количество изображений и если бд то какую выбрать? На вопрос сколько будет изображений - ответа пока не имею, но в планах много.

Comment: БД так же занимает дисковое пространство как  и файлы. Файлы лежащие на диске отдавать клиенту гораздо эффективнее (особенно nginx), чем читать скриптом из БД и отдавать. При повреждении сектора на диске вы потеряете всего один файл конкретного изображения. А с  БД скорее всего придется восстанавливать целиком из бекапа. Так что если вы не собираетесь на лету каждый раз производить программные манипуляции с содержимым графических файлов, лучше их оставить именно файлами

Answer (score 0):

Не мучайте себя. Создайте сервис для хранения, анализа изображений, файлов и т.д. по началу пусть они хранятся в файловой системе. Собирайте статистику по запросам к этим файлам. Далее имея статистику возможно появится смысл хранить часто используемые файлы в оперативной памяти, в кеше (Redis, memcash ...) Старайтесь хранить по уникальным именам чтобы можно было быстро найти полный путь к файлу а оригинальное название файла как часть уникального.

Comment: Хранить файлы в кэше вручную нет большого смысла, потому что любая современная ОС автоматически использует всю свободную память под кэш этих самых файлов

Comment: Спорить не буду в этом тоже большого смысла нет.